# How can I have curried case class constructors?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, jvm, currying, case-class

I wrote the following:

```
case class SuperMessage(message: String)(capitalMessage: String = message.capitalize)
val message = "hello world"
val superMessage = SuperMessage(message)()
```

but I can't do `superMessage.capitalMessage`

What's going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parameters from the second parameter list of a case class are not `val`s by default.

Try

```
case class SuperMessage(message: String)(val capitalMessage: String = message.capitalize)
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Dmytro's answer, I should point out that *all* case class functionality only cares about parameters in the first list, so for example

```
val message1 = SuperMessage("hello world")()
val message2 = SuperMessage("hello world")("surprise")
println(message1 == message2)
```

will print `true`. If that's not what you want, define a separate `apply` method instead:

```
case class SuperMessage(message: String, capitalMessage: String)

object SuperMessage {
  def apply(message: String) = SuperMessage(message, message.capitalize)
}
```